# how to use the same container which was exited in docker

Tags: docker, containers

I had created a lot of containers. I am new to this docker container system.
I do a docker ps -a then I get following result

```
debian@osboxes:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES
a6a62181dcf0        python              "/bin/bash"              About a minute ago   Exited (127) 8 seconds ago                       try1
ed5ef0b8155d        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              22 hours ago         Exited (0) 22 hours ago                          pedantic_ellis
19a4eff3b5e5        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              22 hours ago         Exited (0) 22 hours ago                          assignment4
30933891f08c        eeadc22d21a9        "python3"                22 hours ago         Exited (0) 22 hours ago                          python
ccdab94fd32f        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              28 hours ago         Exited (0) 24 hours ago                          confident_wu
ce462ecfc5f2        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash -v /home/…"   28 hours ago         Exited (127) 28 hours ago                        stupefied_grothendieck
6123f134934c        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              28 hours ago         Exited (1) 28 hours ago                          stupefied_taussig
0ed23a8112a4        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              29 hours ago         Exited (0) 29 hours ago                          vigilant_bartik
c343731b7cde        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              30 hours ago         Exited (0) 29 hours ago                          gallant_ardinghelli
2f95d3b4c1b8        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              30 hours ago         Created                                          nice_hermann
5ebe9f18c744        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              46 hours ago         Created                                          pensive_easley
c1b43edfafb9        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              46 hours ago         Exited (1) 22 hours ago                          adoring_williams
42dea69d1d4e        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              46 hours ago         Created                                          funny_austin
6f736902e650        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              46 hours ago         Exited (1) 46 hours ago                          strange_ride
09306e5ec5d1        1d1a162a72a6        "--name=kaushik"         2 days ago           Created                                          pensive_shtern
699fb2a23e1c        1d1a162a72a6        "--name=kaushik"         2 days ago           Created                                          sharp_feistel
9f7b29ab512e        1d1a162a72a6        "--name=kaushik"         2 days ago           Created                                          elastic_payne2
25bfc74fab3b        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (1) 2 days ago                            festive_einstein
e658dd320297        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (255) 2 minutes ago                       objective_napier
ebae378d9152        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (1) 2 days ago                            brave_ritchie
23c7f4293b30        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (0) 2 days ago                            suspicious_lumiere
5090081f6809        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (1) 2 days ago                            quizzical_keller
425d59be9cbf        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (0) 2 days ago                            distracted_lederberg
11c55ce7f011        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          elastic_noyce
1ccaf0477995        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          mystifying_tu
62528115f4b7        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          determined_meninsky
fca64af2f595        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          elastic_goldwasser
eecb3153bded        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          cool_cray
30b6d61fcac9        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (1) 2 days ago                            quirky_kapitsa
cf992a8b8286        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          hungry_goldstine
0f9a951f7593        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          crazy_wright
e25dcf8a8be8        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Created                                          bold_pasteur
73d068e0d756        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (0) 2 days ago                            condescending_goodall
adda325294cd        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (0) 2 days ago                            serene_wilson
75a9a3262505        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (0) 2 days ago                            hardcore_khorana
e38726a74e9b        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              3 days ago           Exited (255) 2 days ago                          beautiful_clarke
4060dbc85d2d        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              3 days ago           Exited (0) 3 days ago                            strange_yonath
174509213b30        hadoop-build-1001   "/bin/bash"              8 days ago           Exited (255) 7 days ago                          hadoop-c
fa82c595e214        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              8 days ago           Exited (0) 8 days ago                            agitated_edison
4b07fcc45271        python              "python3"                2 weeks ago          Exited (255) 8 days ago                          pyC
1cc06f213eb7        abee520343a4        "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get…"   3 months ago         Exited (100) 3 months ago                        compassionate_kowalevski
8c1eb67f7325        1b1c7b120b48        "/bin/sh -c 'cd /opt…"   3 months ago         Exited (255) 3 months ago                        dreamy_jepsen
1406d7476a28        1180f37ef8b1        "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -…"   3 months ago         Exited (35) 3 months ago                         upbeat_taussig
e88bcf7743e2        f0f5acc11f91        "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get…"   3 months ago         Exited (100) 3 months ago                        tender_cohen
```

I had made some changes in a container which was created using one of hadoop image as below

```
debian@osboxes:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python              latest              eeadc22d21a9        2 weeks ago         933MB
hadoop-build-1001   latest              1d1a162a72a6        3 months ago        2.02GB
hadoop-build        latest              5c1480006f78        3 months ago        1.96GB
ubuntu              xenial              5f2bf26e3524        3 months ago        123MB
```

I powered off the machine and rebooted etc.
I want to know that I made changes to one of the containers say in above output of `docker ps -a` the container was

```
25bfc74fab3b        1d1a162a72a6        "/bin/bash"              2 days ago           Exited (1)
```

how can after a reboot etc I connect or start the same container again.
What I am currently doing is

```
docker run -it 1d1a162a72a6 /bin/bash
```

I make some changes and run a few python programms. But after a reboot all the changes are gone that means those python files which I had edited I have to copy paste them again in the container and do every thing from scratch.I have to install vim each time and then each time I do apt-get update install softwares and then check edit the programe.
I am not able to understand how to go back to same container which was created moments ago before exiting. What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: As mentioned before, Hadoop isn't exactly designed for Docker usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker run` always starts a new container.  You can re-attach to the existing container provided it wasn't started with `--rm` using `docker start`:

```
docker start -ai <CONTAINER_ID>
```

Notice that you should use container ID, *not* image ID as a parameter to `docker start`. See more in Docker help:

```
$ docker start --help

Usage:  docker start [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Start one or more stopped containers

Options:
  -a, --attach               Attach STDOUT/STDERR and forward signals
      --detach-keys string   Override the key sequence for detaching a container
  -i, --interactive          Attach container's STDIN
```

Answer (score 0):

> I had made some changes in a container... after a reboot all the changes are gone that means those python files which I had edited I have to copy paste them again in the container and do every thing from scratch.I have to install vim each time and then each time I do apt-get update install softwares and then check edit the programe.

Containers are, by definition, immutable. What you were editing was a temporary runtime layer. If the container stopped or exited, you lose those changes.

In order to preserve changes, you must edit the Dockerfile and rebuild the container in order to create those immutable layers that the image contains

---

Realistically, you'd use a volume mount from the host into the container and edit code locally, which syncs into the container. No need for text editors or repeated apt updates

Comment: But it's possible to re-attach to the stopped container providing it wasn't start with `--rm` using `docker start`.

Comment: What if the host machine restarts?

Comment: It depends where Docker files are stored and if contents of these directories is gone after reboot. For example, some systems mount /tmp in RAM but some do not.

Comment: AFAIK, /tmp is always cleaned, regardless of how it's configured. I think you're referring to the tmpfs volume

Comment: No, `/tmp` is not always cleared - Slackware doesn't do that, for example. There is no requirement to do that. There might be some "standards" but in the open source world everyone can come up with their own standard.